# Matlab Number (Figure) Representation

Tags: matlab

I am confused with how numbers are represented in Matlab.

Considering this sequence of computations, carried out using 64-bit arithmetic in
Matlab:

```
format longg
i = 0:8;
a = sin(i*(pi/2))
```

When doing these calculations by hand, I would expect to see the results a = 0, 1, 0, –1, 0,
etc. But that is not what Matlab shows. Why not? Is it because pi is not in machine number?

In addition,

```
format long
a = 2^(60);
b = 20000;
c = a + b;
d = c – a
```

When doing these calculations by hand, I would expect to see the result d = 20000. But that is not what Matlab returns. Why not?